# How to prevent bash to autocomplete the trailing dot?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Let's say I have a filename and different extensions to it:

```
test.tex
test.pdf
```

It is easier to type just the filename without extension, then the whole filename. This is possible, because corresponding program know the extension which they need and append it automatically. The following examples work perfectly:

```
tex test
pdf-viewer test
```

But using bash completion here constantly annoys me by adding the trailing dot. For example:

```
tex te<TAB>
```

is turned into

```
tex test.
```

But the application will fail with error; I have to hit backspace each time after I hit `<TAB>` :-(

How to tell bash not to add trailing dot when doing autocompletion?

Comment: Bash autocompletes the longest common prefix. That in your case the longest common prefix ends in a dot is an accident.

Comment: @AlexP this does not prove that it is not possible to tell bash to exclude this dot from autocompletion

Comment: Note that accepting `test` in place of `test.tex` is a convenience, not a requirement. One option is modify the completion for `tex` to *only* expand to names ending in `.tex`. I know it involves the `-G` option to the `complete` command, but I can never figure out how to make it work correctly. I'll post an answer if I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an easier way, but this seems to work:

```
texfiles () { names=( "$2"*.tex ); COMPREPLY=( "${names[@]%.tex}" ); }

complete -F texfiles tex
```

This first sets up a shell function called `texfiles`.  It uses the second command line argument (`$2`, the word typed by the user on the command line before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete the word), and populates the `COMPREPLY` array with all names that matches `"$2"*.tex`.

For each of these names, the suffix `.tex` is removed before adding it to the array.

The `complete` command is then used to tell the shell to execute the `texfiles` function for file name completion for the `tex` command *specifically*. You may repeat the same `complete` command for all commands that should complete `.tex` files in the same way. For `pdf-viewer` you may want to create a corresponding `pdffiles` function (the names of these functions are arbitrary).

This is it in action (`<tab>` signifies me pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key):

```
bash-4.4$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Sep 28 21:43 README.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Sep 28 21:12 file.tex
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Sep 28 21:24 file2.tex
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Sep 28 21:25 hello.tex

bash-4.4$ tex <tab><tab>
file   file2  hello
bash-4.4$ tex

bash-4.4$ tex f<tab>ile<tab><tab>
file   file2
bash-4.4$ tex file
```

(the `ile` in `file` is inserted by the shell)

Read the "Programmable Completion" section of the `bash` manual for the gory details.

Comment: You could replace the `for` loop with an array operation: `arr=("$2"*.tex); COMPREPLY=( "${arr[@]%.tex}")`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom completion spec for the `tex` command to your `.bashrc`. After specifying that `tex` should use filename completion, you can add a filter to remove any argument that *doesn't* match `*.tex` from the possible completions.

```
complete -f -X '!*.tex'
```

Now, if you had `test.tex`, `test.aux`, and `test.pdf` in your directory, a prefix of `test` would *only* complete to `test.tex`. This completes the full name of the file you want, rather than skipping the `.` to create the shortcut.